# Import STL files by Qt3D module: how to do configuration of light and material

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I have used somebody's code uploaded [here on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/amahta/3d_viewer) to open and view STL files with Qt3D. The code has an entity which corresponds to imported STL model:

```
        Entity
        {
            id: monkeyEntity
            components: [
                SceneLoader
                {
                    id: sceneLoader
                }
            ]
        }
```

The above `sceneLoader` is loading the imported STL model by a QML dialog:

```
FileDialog
{
    id: fileDialog
    onAccepted:
    {
        sceneLoader.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
    }
}
```

But when I import the STL files, the lighting is not working. No matter how I change the light or material the imported 3D STL model is all white without showing the 3D shape:

[image: STL model is all white, not showing the 3D shape]

However when I use [Blender software](https://www.blender.org) to convert STL file to Wavefront OBJ file, then the imported OBJ file into the Qt3D app shows up properly:

[image: Wavefront OBJ model is viewed properly]

---

I tried many light and material features of Qt3D but I couldn't make the STL model be viewed properly. Can anyone provide an example of Qt3D light/material configuration which would work for STL files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I build/run the app with Qt 5.9.0, it works fine, i.e. it can import STL files with all the colors:

[image]

However with Qt 5.11, it doesn't work fine:

[image]

I think the problem is `SceneLoader` which works differently in Qt 5.9.0 and Qt 5.11.

---

Please take a look at [this report on Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69385) and [this report on assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/2059)